# Formatting options in comments

Tags: discussion, comments

I noticed that user [Ce4](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/15713/ce4) had hyperlinks in the comments he/she made. For instance, the question "[Android connected to Car system](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/34327/android-connected-to-car-system)" the comment made by ce4 is as follows:
[image]

I wonder how this is achieved as I am unable to have formatting options in comments that I make, which makes the comment bit unreadable. I would be surprised if it just because of lack of in sufficient reputation as this should be available for any user as it only helps in better readability (if correctly applied [image]).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you click the "help" link next to a comment box, you'll get a popup with the following information:

> Comments use mini-Markdown formatting: `[link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold**```code``. The post author will always be notified of your comment. To also notify a previous commenter, mention their user name: `@peter` or `@PeterSmith` will both work. [Learn more…](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

If you follow the "Learn more..." link you'll get more information about formatting comments than you would think there would be.

Answer (score 2):

Comments use the same mark down as answers.

You can use this syntax for links: `[link text](url)`

Comment: Not completely, some of the extended features are disabled, such as <key>key tags</key>. You can see all the supported features in [markdown help](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting).

Comment: It is still the same markdown - just some things are disabled.

Comment: They call it "mini-Markdown".